# why can't other person access node.js server that i made?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

i made a server with node.js like below:

```
// basicServer.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

and it worked in my Mac and i can access. But, my parallel window can not access.

Of course, other in other computers, too.

Should i make a server with apache or NGINX?

Could you explain why other computers can not access my node js server?

Comment: it will be displayed to other computers if they are connected in a lan or if you have a public ip,note if you have public ip you might have to write your ip code instead of 127.0.0.1 in browsers but only if you are not connected in lan

Comment: You can also use your machine name instead. like. //mymachinename:1337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your application to run on `0.0.0.0`:

```
// basicServer.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(1337, '0.0.0.0');
```

Now you can use your IP to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same private network they should be able to access using your private IP. For example http://192.168.1.33:1337/.
If you want them to access from outside you'll have to map the 1337 port to your private server IP.